# PHP MySQLi Pagination LIMIT, WHERE and ORDER BY `date` DESC problems

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

I am creating project not for profit and have problems with pagination. First idea was "Load more" <- but it's in dreams only. Maybe MySQL syntax is wrong. How to fix this code? Maybe there's a better solution? I tried all combinations "..",'..', ``. This can also be exploited by using SQL injections?

```
  MySQLi connection:


$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','tablename');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
/* Change character set to utf8 */
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit();
}

  Paggination:

  $items_per_page = 5;  
  $login = $_SESSION['login'];
  $per_page = $items_per_page;
  if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $page = $_GET['page'];
  }else {
  $page = 1;
  }
  $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;
  //Selecting the data from db   
  $date = $mysqli->query("SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE posts_author = '.$login.' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT $start_from, $per_page");
  while($row = $date->fetch_array()){
  echo $row["post_id"];
  }
  //



  //Select all from DB
  $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE posts_author='$login' ORDER BY date DESC");
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
  $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);
  //Going to first page
  echo '<a href="' .ABSOLUTE_URL. '/post/1">first page</a> '; 
  for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++){
  echo '<a href="' .ABSOLUTE_URL. '/post/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
  };
  // Going to last page
  echo '<a href="' .ABSOLUTE_URL. '/post/'.$total_pages.'">last page</a> ';
```

Comment: _“This can also be exploited by using SQL injections?”_ – of course it can. Why do you even have to ask this - did you not read up on what the problem with SQL injection actually is? If you bothered to understand that, you would already know that the code as shown is vulnerable. _“How to fix this code?”_ – well definitively _not_ by just dumping it here for us to figure out what is even wrong in the first place. Please go read [ask], and then give us a proper problem description.

Comment: I don't see the reason for downvoting this, he's asking for little help overthere, i guess you all who downvoted just looking for badges..

Comment: Instead of doing `mysqli_num_rows($result);` after selecting all records, you could do `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM posts WHERE posts_author=?`  and get the result of that. It's also a good place to start using parametrised queries and prepared statements. As is your code is simple to migrate to using that and you will have to worry a bit less about SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be exploited,
you should consider of using `mysqli_real_escape_string`: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

For bugs, i see it here:

```
//Selecting the data from db   
  $date = $mysqli->query("SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE posts_author = '.$login.' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT $start_from, $per_page");
  while($row = $date->fetch_array()){
  echo $row["post_id"];
  }
```

You were used single quotes with dots for `'.$login.'` instead of using double quotes and your query should execute fine.

If you got some other problems, update answer where did you stuck, what's not working and what have you tried.